# How to select multiple columns in pandas dataframe after doing some operation on one column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a `dataframe` with 7 columns. I'm only interested in columns `A` and `B`. Column `B` contains numerical values.

What I want to do is **select only columns A and B, after doing some mathematical operation `f` on B**. The `sql` equivalent of what I'm saying is:

```sql
SELECT A, f(B)
FROM df;
```

I know that I can select just columns A and B by doing `df[['A', 'B']]`. Also, I can just add another column `f_B` saying: `df['f_B'] = f(df['B'])`, and then select `df[['A', 'f_B']]`.

However, is there a way of doing it without adding an extra column? What if when `f` is as simple as a `divide by 100` or something?

EDIT: I do not want to use `pandasql`

EDIT2: Sharing sample input and expected output:

Input:

```
A | B | C | D
--------------
a | 1 | c | d
b | 2 | c | d
c | 3 | c | d
d | 4 | c | d
```

Expected output (only columns A and B required), assuming `f` is **multiply by 2**:

```
A | B
-----
a | 2
b | 4
c | 6
d | 8
```

Comment: ``df.B.div(100)`` ?

Comment: I also want `df.A` along with `df.B.div(100)`, and hence the entire doubt :/

Comment: kindly share sample data, with expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy updated the question with samples

Comment: ``df.loc[:, ["A", "B"]].assign(B=lambda x: x.B * 2)`` ?

Comment: @sammywemmy, that works. However, this is the same as selecting the entire column and then applying `f`. Which leads to the next question, in sql, when we do a 'select A, B*2 from df', does a similar thing happen? Like an intermediate table being created, and then the operations are done?

Comment: the entire column has to be selected, for the computation to occur. In Sql, I believe the columns are selected as well. Unless I misunderstand your question

Comment: That would mean that all the values are visited twice, once to create an intermediate table, and then doing the operation. Wouldn't the design be such that the values are computed from the desired column 'on the fly'?

Answer (score 2):

First you take only the columns you need:

```
df = df[['A', 'B']]  # replace the original df with a smaller one
new_df = df[['A', 'B']] # or allocate a new space
```

1. You can simply do:

   ```
   df.B = df.B / 10
   ```
2. Using lambda:

   ```
   df.B = df.B.apply(lambda value: value / 10)
   ```
3. For more complicated cases:

   ```
   def f(value):
     # some logic
     result = value ** 2
     return result

   df.B = df.B.apply(f)
   ```